# Copy paste is not working in command prompt neither right click or keyboard shortcuts in Windows 10

Tags: cmd, copy-paste, windows-10-desktop

Win 10 copy paste is not working in cmd from right click neither keyboard short cuts as well. Nothing happens if I try to paste some text in prompt. Reason is unknown to me. Any help?

Comment: This is probably a better question for superuser

Comment: I had this problem, right click the title bar in command prompt, choose properties, untick Quick Edit Mode. start a new command prompt and check that right click works again.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Right-click on the title-bar of your `cmd` window. [Properties] - Options - check "QuickEdit Mode". Now when you right click, it will immediately paste. To copy, select the text you want and press enter.

You may also want to change the defaults for future instances. Same thing, but [Defaults] instead of [Properties]

Comment: In my windows 10 pro, the above mentioned properties are already set, but it still does not work.

Comment: @nam: it's not Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V. To copy a marked text to clipboard, press ENTER or right mouse button. To paste, press right mouse button.

Comment: Remote Desktop can cause issues with Cmd copy/paste as well.  You might have to close and reopen to get the copy/paste to work, despite these settings.

Comment: @MacGyver: yes, changing [Defaults] changes it for future sessions (while [Properties] change it for the current session only)

Comment: Do what @Stephan suggested.
Afterwards, to **copy** some text, you need to select the text you wish to copy, and then *right-click* it.
To **paste** the text, *right-click* where you wish to paste.