# Is there a way to keep CMD running for 24 hours?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a Batch file that executes a code for every hour for 24 hours but I noticed that sometimes the timeout 3600 line of code will freeze until the user hit any button, is there a way to avoid this? The code basically turns on and off Airplane mode atop of every hour then screenshots data usage for the past hour. Please see below for code. Let me know if you have a better way to run this code other than Batch :)

```
set /a index = 0


::Unlock PDM
adb shell input keyevent 82
timeout 1
adb shell input keyevent 82
adb shell input text 1111
timeout 1


::Screenshot data usage
adb shell am start -a android.settings.DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS
timeout 1
adb shell input tap 550 1500
timeout 4
adb shell input swipe 600 2050 600 1900
timeout 1
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/%index%_a1.png
timeout 1

:While
if %index% leq 21 (

::APM On
echo.
echo Enabling APM
::Launch APM Settings
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS
timeout 1
::Toggle On
adb shell input tap 825 325
timeout 1
::Navigate to Op5
adb shell am start com.insulet.myblue.pdm
timeout 1
::Turn BLE On
adb shell input tap 550 1600
echo check 2
timeout 2


::Screenshot data usage
adb shell am start -a android.settings.DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS
timeout 4
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/%index%_a2.png
timeout 1


::Navigate to Op5
adb shell am start com.insulet.myblue.pdm

::Timeout for 60 min
timeout 3600 /nobreak

::Unlock PDM
adb shell input keyevent 82
timeout 1
adb shell input keyevent 82
adb shell input text 1111
timeout 1
echo check 4
timeout 2


::APM Off
echo.
echo Disabling APM
::Launch APM Settings
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS
timeout 1
::Toggle Off
adb shell input tap 825 325
timeout 1
::Navigate to Op5
adb shell am start com.insulet.myblue.pd
echo check 5
timeout 2


::Timeout for 10 min
timeout 600 /nobreak

::Unlock PDM
adb shell input keyevent 82
timeout 1
adb shell input keyevent 82
adb shell input text 1111
timeout 1
echo check 6
timeout 2


::Screenshot data usage
adb shell am start -a android.settings.DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS
timeout 4
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/%index%_b1.png
timeout 1
echo check 7


::Navigate to Op5
adb shell am start com.insulet.myblue.pdm
echo check 8
timeout 2


set /a "index = index + 1"
echo # of runs: %index%
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ENDDDD**************************************
goto :while
)
```

Comment: Instead of having a timeout built into the script, why not remove that line and have the rest of the script run via Task Scheduler once per hour?

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing, I will defiantly look into this. Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably have "Quick Edit Mode" enabled (which causes the window to "freeze" (stop showing output) when you click inside it. See [this "opposite" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698674/2152082) for how to change it.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914664/cmd-randomly-stops-updating)

Comment: I just did this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CMD can definitely run for 24 hours, so long as your PC has no interruptions that may affect it, but aside that, it can be live for 24 hours.

Comment: You've responded to the title, but not the contents of the question. Obviously there's no reason a script can't run for 24 hours (I once had a script run for two months straight), but they're having issues with their script freezing and they don't know why.