# Windows pauses my program when I run it from cmd and leave the window idle. How do I tell it not to?

Tags: cmd

I've written a simple application in C that is quite CPU intensive. I run it from a command line, e.g. ".\my_program.exe". I have noticed that when I leave the computer idle, sometimes even if I just focus away from the cmd window, the process effectively pauses. When I click on the cmd window, it resumes regular progress again.

Is there a way I can instruct windows to prioritise such a command?

Comment: Does the process pause, or does only the output stop? How do you know it stopped?

Comment: The program periodically prints to stdout. This output stops, and when I click back on the cmd window it resumes.

Comment: Disable quickEditMode ([here is how to ENable it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698674/2152082) - do the opposite)

Comment: Here is something interesting. I wrote a little program that every second, it beeps, prints an incremented number **to stdout**, and the current time. When I clicked on the terminal text, selecting it, the program did seem to stop, since the next time printed was quite larger, and it didn't beep in between the prints. Even when I set `stdout` as unbuffered, or when I flushed it. However, when I printed to a file instead of `stdout`, the program did not stop. So, this probably has to do with the implementation of `printf()`.

Comment: I have tried to use Windows function `WriteConsole()`, and the result was the same, with `stdout` and `stderr`. So, it seems to be a Windows thing.

Comment: Does deactivating "Quick Edit Mode" help?

Comment: @Schilive trying that now. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: @Schilive working so far!

Comment: @DJames, that's great! I understand the reasoning behind Quick Edit Mode, but it is not obvious. If one is doing a time-sensitive command-line application, and they are not aware of it, they can get screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably happening because of "Quick Edit Mode", as said "Stephan" on the question's comments. Since you are using C, you can deactivate it using the Win32 API, as follows.

```c
HADNLE handle_input;
DWORD console_mode;
handle_input = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

GetConsoleMode(handle_input, &console_mode);
console_mode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE;
console_mode |= ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
SetConsoleMode(handle_input, console_mode);
```

You can also do it manually for a CMD instance, by the following steps. If you want to change the default, just click "Default" instead of "Properties".

1. Click with the right mouse button on the title bar.
2. Click on "Properties".
3. On the menu "Options", toggle the checkbox named "Quick Edit Mode".